# windows 8 Modern UI Applications

Tags: windows, windows-8.1

How do I remove duplicate entries in the Modern UI Application folder?  I am running Windows 8.1 using Stardocks Start8 Menu.  The Modern UI Application Folder lists duplicate Scan Images.  I would like to remove the duplicates.  Right-clicking only gives me the option to pin the item.

Answer (score 0):

It'll take you 10 seconds:

1. Right-click the Start button and select **Configure Start8...**.  The *Stardock Star8 Configuration* dialog appears.
2. On the left (gray) pane, click on **Desktop**.
3. On the right pane, check Hide Modern UI applications from the Windows 7 style menu.